# Removing Unwanted CSS

Tags: 7, theming

I have removed default css files using a code below, but still it is showing some unwanted css files

```
<?php
function _phptemplate_variables($hook, $vars)
{
 $css = drupal_add_css();
 unset($css['all']['module']['modules/system/system.css']);
 unset($css['all']['module']['modules/system/defaults.css']);
 $vars['styles'] = drupal_get_css($css);
 return $vars;
}
?>
```

In firebug GOw.css is appearing I dont know from where, can anybody please tell me how can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

To find where a specific stylesheet is coming from, scan your Drupal directory for that file's name. This is the easiest way to find it.

To disable a stylesheet, you can either use preprocess hook, or add the following to your theme's `.info` file:

```
stylesheets[all][] = css/removed/GOw.css
```

Just make sure that the file does not exist, and Drupal won't include it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanku @Topsitemakers, the path from where all unwanted css is coming `theme_name/sites/default/files/css`, may I delete this folder?

Comment: Actually drupal automatically creates that folder again and again

Comment: Look further into which module is trying to add that stylesheet, maybe it has some additional logic. I'm not familiar with `GOw.css` file, so you have to look it up in your installation. Simply search the code in whole Drupal dir for stylesheet name.

Comment: I have unchecked the compress css and js option, now it is ok